# How strongly supported is a conclusion drawn from the correlation of 10 observations?

Tags: spearman-rho, rule-of-thumb

The Spearman’s rank correlation coefficient calculated for these observations is 0.826 (p<0.005). Is there something like a "rule of thumb" minimum number of observations?

Comment: What is the "conclusion" to which the title refers?

Comment: What I mean by the conclusion is "there is a relationship between the dependant and independent variables".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no minimum number of observations. The value of statistical significance takes into account the amount of error associated with your effect size (0.826). The amount of error is inherently associated with the amount of observations you have. Since the value is statistically significant, you can conclude that your finding is "supported".

Answer (score 1):

To semi-precisely estimate r requires about 400 observations.  See [Section 8.5.2 of BBR](http://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf).  The graph there will allow you to estimate the margin of error for r when n=10.  It's not good.

Answer (score 0):

A p-value is, put simply, a compromise between "strength" of the trend and number of observations. Therefore you should set a threshold on what your "highest allowed" p-value should be.

The main reason for that is that p-values are expressed as a "probability of the effect appearing randomly", while finding criteria for minimum sample size would be really hard to do consistently (also, we do not always have control on sample size ourselves)

p-values lower than 0.005 like the one you have are often considered enough. 0.05 is often chosen as a threshold, but depending on your subject area, you may want to be careful and choose a more restrictive one.